# Pass Attributes before CustomView inflation in Fragment based on holder Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-custom-view

I have a Fragment which includes a custom/compound view in layout.

```
<app.view.ControlLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/controlLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_control_size"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/offset_distance"
    custom:horizontal="true" />
```

Fragment has been attached to different activities in layouts, such as:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/controlLayout"
        android:name="app.controllers.ControlFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_control_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/offset_distance"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_control" />
```

The custom view has following attributes:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ControlLayout">
        <attr name="horizontal" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="callBtnVisibility" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Based on to which Activity my Control Fragment is attached, I want to pass callBtnVisibility attribute to my custom view. One solution is handle the login in the code without using attributes:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_control, container, false);

        if (getActivity() instanceof MyActivity) {
            ((ControlLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.controlLayout)).hideCallButton();
        }
```

I wonder if I can somehow manage it without using following login. So that before controlLayout get inflated in the fragment, I can pass the attribute to it, and handle the logic in Constructor or init method of custom view:

```
public ControlLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.ControlLayout,
                0, defStyle);

        final boolean horizontal = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ControlLayout_horizontal, false);
        final boolean callButtonIsVisible = a.getBoolean(
                R.styleable.ControlLayout_callBtnVisibility, true);

        a.recycle();

        if(callButtonIsVisible) {
            mCallButton = new Button(getContext());
            mCallButton.setId(R.id.button_call);
            ...
```

Comment: You could just pass in `defStyle` to the constructor, assign it to a member variable, and then check it's value in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Where should I pass it? ControlLayout is a customView which inflated in Fragment.

Comment: It looks like you could pass it into the constructor of each Fragment that uses ControlLayout, and then call `hideCallButton()`, or not, based on the value passed in.

Comment: Fragment constructor will not be called. As I explained in the question Fragment is part of Activity layout.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Sorry, I miss-understood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onInflated in fragment lifecycle which is called before onAttach() can solve this issue.